# Pandas - inserting a comma on a number

Tags: python, pandas, format

I’m using Python and pandas and I’m using a dataframe that has temperatures (Celsius) on it, I worked it and right now they follow this pattern, e.g.

362
370
380
385
376

I want to make it have the comma between the second and third number,
e.g. 36,2
But I just can’t do this, is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If they are all numbers and not strings, wouldn't it be possible to divide everything by 10?

Comment: I was thinking on having the 0 even if they were 370, so 37.0. But yeah, that’s an alternative in case there’s no other way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Try with division + [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html#pandas-dataframe-astype) + [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace):

```
df['temp'] = (df['temp'] / 10).astype(str).str.replace('.', ',', regex=False)
```

```
   temp
0  36,2
1  37,0
2  38,0
3  38,5
4  37,6
```

---

DataFrame Used:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'temp': [362, 370, 380, 385, 376]})
```

```
   temp
0   362
1   370
2   380
3   385
4   376
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want the last digit to be separated by a comma (for example, 88 should be 8,8). In that case, this will work:

```
ls = [362, 370, 380, 385, 376]
ls = [f"{str(item)[:-1]},{str(item)[-1]}" for item in ls]
# ['36,2', '37,0', '38,0', '38,5', '37,6']
```

Where:

- `str(item)[:-1]` get's all digits except the final one
- `str(item)[-1]` get's just the final digit

In a dataframe, your values are stored as a pandas series. In that case:

```
import pandas as pd
ls = pd.Series([362, 370, 380, 385, 376])
ls = ls.astype("str").map(lambda x : f"{x[:-1]},{x[-1]}")
```

Or more specifically

```
df["Your column"] = df["Your column"].astype("str").map(lambda x : f"{x[:-1]},{x[-1]}")
```

Output:

```
0    36,2
1    37,0
2    38,0
3    38,5
4    37,6
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to convert this integer data to string in order to enter the ','.

For example:

```
temp=362

x = str(temp)[:-1]+','+str(temp)[-1]
```

You could use this in a loop or a list comprehension which was already mentioned. (They can be trickier to understand, so I provided this instead) Hope it helps!